# Number of ways to remove some cards from a deck

Tags: combinatorics

I'm currently studying discrete mathematics and I've just bought "Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction" by Edward A. Scheinerman.

The book is awesome but unfortunately it doesn't contain the answers for the proposed exercises, so. I'm not sure if my solution to this exercise is correct.

Given a standard deck with 52 cards, one have to remove 4 cards. In how many different ways can you remove the 4 cards considering that this 4 cards are all from different numbers (considering king, queen and jack as numbers) and suits.

My solution: Initially, we can choose any of the 52 cards, then, our possible cards decrease by subtracting all cards from the same suit of the last chosen one and all cards with the same value of the last one. So, the result should be:  $52 * 37 * 25 * 14$

Is it right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, there are $52$ ways to choose the first card. Once you’ve chosen it, you must choose the second card from one of the other three suits, and it must be one of the other $12$ denominations within those suits, so it must be one of $3\cdot12=36$ cards. You now have a choice of $13-2=11$ denominations in $2$ suits, so there are only $11\cdot2=22$ possibilities for the third card. The fourth card must come from the remaining suit and must differ in denomination from the first three cards, so it must be one of $13-3=10$ cards. Thus, there are

$$52\cdot36\cdot22\cdot10$$

possible **sequences** of four cards satisfying the stated conditions. Each **set** of four cards satisfying those conditions can be picked in $4!=24$ different orders, so if the problem is to find the number of **sets** of four cards of different suits and denominations, you must now divide by $24$ to get

$$\frac{52\cdot36\cdot22\cdot10}{24}=13\cdot6\cdot22\cdot10=17160$$

sets.

Your basic approach was correct, at least for counting the sequences of four cards of different suits and denominations; you just didn’t correctly count the number of valid choices remaining after one, two, and three cards were drawn. I did it above by counting the valid choices that are left. You can also do it by counting the excluded choices. For instance, after the first card is drawn, you must exclude it, the other $3$ cards of the same denomination, and the other $12$ cards of the same suit; that’s a total of $1+3+12=16$ cards, leaving $52-16=36$ acceptable choices for the second card.

Answer (score 0):

We want to end up with one each of $\spadesuit$, $\heartsuit$,  $\diamondsuit$, and  $\clubsuit$.

The $\spadesuit$ can be chosen in $13$ ways. For each such choice, the $\heartsuit$ can be chosen in $12$ ways, and so on, for a total of $(13)(12)(11)(10)$.